# What does # (hash) mean when it doesn't mean Windows key?

Tags: autohotkey

Not sure where to search or how to define the keywords. What is the difference between the following?

```
#IfWinActive, Some Window Title
```

```
IfWinActive, Some Window Title
```

What is the `#` doing there? I know that in shortcuts, `#` stands for Windows key, but surely this has to mean something else.

I had been trying to make up a script and the `If-else` blocks did not work at all. Finally I figured out that it's because I added the `#` symbol. But I don't find any documentation regarding this kind of use of the `#` symbol.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hash is a totally different command.  If you search the index in the autohotkey documentation, you will find an entry for both `IfWinActive` and `#IfWinActive`.

> [The hash...] Creates context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings. Such hotkeys perform
>   a different action (or none at all) depending on the type of window
>   that is active or exists.
>
> The #IfWin directives are positional: they affect all hotkeys and
>   hotstrings physically beneath them in the script. They are also
>   mutually exclusive; that is, only the most recent one will be in effect.

The `#` only represents the windows key when you use it as a hotkey assignment designation.  In AutoHotkey, any time you see a `#` at the beginning of a command it has something to do with AutoHotkey directives.

**Conclusion:**

If you just want regular `if`-`else` statemens and don't need to affect the context of hotkeys, then don't use the `#`.

Comment: Ha ha ha haha - I beat you that time, Joe.

Comment: :D hahaha true. You have! :)